# simple_captcha doesn't display image on production, rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In the browser console shows this error.
Any idea what's wrong?

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://innovationgateway.md/simple_captcha?code=be5a034949264cf75ea871c605781ff4b892ded5&time=1415635452
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the default directory for saving image file is /tmp so I think it's worth a try to change to some directory inside your project like that:

```
SimpleCaptcha.setup do |sc|     
 sc.tmp_path = Rails.root.join('public').to_s
end
```

Also you could try to comment out the following config, assuming you're using nginx

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'
```

but on my vps it works without this config...

Or maybe your simple_captcha simply doesnt generate the file which you need to check.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem?

Comment: @MrH I didn't have this problem, I just gave a couple of options that might have caused it.